# number of vcore in yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am a novice in Yarn. I installed Single Node Hadoop Yarn in my computer, everything is default.
I open the webpage of ResourceManager, it said my cluster is 8GB RAM and 8 vcores.
But actually, my computer has 3GB of ram and 2 cores (I see information in /proc/meminfo and /proc/cpuinfo).
I wonder why Yarn shows too many ram and vcore?
Can everyone explain to me?
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yarn gets the information on the memory and cores available to it from the yarn-site.xml conf file, via these two parameters:

```
<!-- Default 8GB -->
<property>
  <description>Max available memory on each data node.</description>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>8192</value>
</property>

<!-- Default 8. -->
<property>
  <description>Max available cores data node.</description>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
  <value>8</value>
</property>
```

So the reason it is picking up 8GB and 8 cores is because those are the defaults if you don't specify anything else. These settings are probably too high for a small machine like yours. There are some other memory related setting you probably need to tweak when running on a small machine.

In yarn-site.xml:

```
<!-- Default 1024 -->
<property>
  <description>Minimum allocation unit.</description>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>

<!-- Biggest memory allocation a container can request. Set to available memory -->
<property>
  <description>Max allocation unit.</description>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>yarnavailablememory</value>
</property>

<property>
  <description>Minimum increment setting - set to same as min-allocation</description>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>
```

In mapred-site.xml:

```
<!-- small cluster memory settings -->
<!-- Default 1024. Recommend setting to 4096. Should not be higher than YARN max allocation -->
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>

<!-- Default 1024. Recommend setting to 4096. Should not be higher than YARN max allocation -->
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>

<!-- Default 1536. Recommend 1024 -->
<property>
  <description>Application master allocation</description>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>

<!-- Recommend heapsizes to be 75% of mapreduce.map/reduce.memory.mb -->
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx204m</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx204m</value>
</property> 

<property>
  <description>Application Master JVM opts</description>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx204m</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very appreciate about this. However, I wonder can I run 8 jobs (each is <1GB, 1 vcore>) at the same time.

Comment: When running on a small local machine, you should probably adjust the settings down a bit or it will overwhelm you machine. I will edit my comment about to add some more info.

Comment: Thank you. I am very appreciate about this.

Comment: Awesome. I understand the issue

Comment: I am very appreciate about your answer. But I still wonder about the number of vcore. 
For example, if you have a computer with 1 CPU, and the CPU has 2 cores, that means you could use at most 2 cores, no more. 
Actually, my computer has 2 physical cores, obviously, when I run any jobs, application, I can see that either/both these 2 cores work. 
But why hadoop/yarn shows me that its node has 8 vcore, then when we run jobs in hadoop, it says some vcores used. It is not precise because the physical cores are 2.
The same theory with Memory.

Comment: Yarn does not query your system to detect the memory or cores - it only uses the settings mentioned above. Each time a container is started it allocates a vcore and some memory. If yarn allocates all of its resources (memory and vcores) based on the settings (not the real machine capacity) it will not start more containers until some of the others finish. With the default settings of 8GB and 8, Yarn will try to run too much at once on your small laptop, but the defaults may sense on a mid-sized server machine.